# fallback to other column in globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize

In [globalize/globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize),
I want to fallback to other column.
sample source.

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :foo, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    Post.create_translation_table! hoge: :string
  end
end
```

---

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this not work. but I want to like this.
  translates :hoge, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => :foo
end
```

Though it seems like double management of column `hoge` and `foo`, I plan to display the content of column `hoge` in case column `foo` is empty. You can edit the content of open source `globalize`.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in globalize documentation, you don't need to add the translatable column to the table migration, but pass it as an argument of create translation table

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      # no foo column specified here
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  Post.create_translation_table! foo: :string
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :foo, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
end
```

This will not create separate columns for each language, but a new entry in the translations table for each language associated to each entry in the main model table.

If you have correctly set

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

and set `:en` as the default language, getting the value of the foo field whenever the locale-specific value is missing will default to the English value. For example, given two posts (`post1`and `post2`) with data

```
[#<Post::Translation id: 1, post_id: 1, locale: "en", foo: 'Italy'>,
  #<Post::Translation id: 2, post_id: 1, locale: "jp", foo: 'Hetalia'>,
  #<Post::Translation id: 3, post_id: 2, locale: "en", foo: 'Finland'>,
  #<Post::Translation id: 4, post_id: 2, locale: "jp", foo: ''>]
```

if your locale is to Japanese, you will get

```
post1.foo # => 'Hetalia'
post2.foo # => 'Finland'
```

Comment: thank you. but my system need to fallback to other column.

Comment: Then are you sure that globalize is the right gem for you? If the columns are not simply translations of each other, than the alternative is to define your own setter and getters for those columns, and not use globalize at all